# Change Color on change of Theme

Tags: android, android-theme

There are two themes in my android project and i have a color resource color1 as

> `<color name="color1">#b0b0ff</color>`

And i am using this resource at some place in my program like

> Resources res = context.getResources(); 
>   mycolor=res.getColor(R.color.color1);

Problem: 
I want to change color on changing the theme. Is that possible? 
I read [Android Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) page but i couldn't find any way which fulfills my demand.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to apply the color for? and what do you mean by theme? is it the theme of your app? or something else

Comment: Color is used in my app for drawing on Canvas and i want to make it a theme based system i.e. I have a theme selector which changes theme on selection from spinner.  
  
Now I want to use different color scheme to draw on canvas. It should be according to my theme.   
Yes this is theme for my app.